# Skipping data in a binary file in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm writing a file reader for my (binary) format and I sometimes need to skip some portion of the file.

I could do `fileobject.read(howmuchtoskip)` for that, but I guess that will load the unneeded part to memory and will be slow.

Can I just set the "index" of the "pointer" or whatever that's called?

Answer (score 7):

Use `fileobject.seek(offset)`.